# is there a well known function or mixtures of functions where $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x^x)-f(x)=1$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing, logarithms

Is there a well known function or mixtures of functions where $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x^x)-f(x)=1$
My first thought was yes because you can take logs of logs of logs, but when we do that we get infinity for all $f(x)=\ln(\ln(\ln(\dots\ln(x)))))$

let $\ln_n(x)= \ln(\ln(\ln(\overset{\mathrm{n}}{\dots}\ln(x))))$

Then $\ln_n(x^x)=\ln_{n-1}(x\ln(x))$ and $\ln_n(x) = \ln_{n-1}(\ln(x))$ and $\ln_n(x) = \ln(\ln_{n-1}(x))$

$\ln_n(x^x)-\ln_n(x)=\ln(ln_{n-2}(x\ln(x))/(ln_{n-2}(\ln(x))))$

$\lim_{x\to\infty} \ln(ln_{n-2}(x\ln(x))/(ln_{n-2}(\ln(x))))=\ln(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{ln_{n-2}(x\ln(x))}{(ln_{n-2}(\ln(x)))})=\infty$

This isn't a full proof that $\ln_n(x)$ never works but every time I solve the limit it's infinity. So I'm not even sure a function can have the property $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x^x)-f(x)=1$. I would like to know a full proof for $c\times\ln_n(x)$ is never a soultion, and I would like to know if a function can have this as a property $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x^x)-f(x)=1$.

Comment: @AlannRosas yes I think I fixed it.

Comment: I think you are trying to recreate this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-logarithm ?

Comment: @zwim maybe or something like it, it states that the super logarithm is only defined for $b$, $b^b$, $b^{b^b}$, ... It states it can be extended but I don't think (I may be wrong) that it will have the limit property. $ln_n(x)$ is just doing the logarithm n times to x, where n is a natural number.